# Overriding web config file at the time of deployment in ASP.NET and IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

We are using ASP.NET for our web application which is hosted in IIS 8.5. ASP.NET uses a web.config file to store all application and IIS related configurations. Whenever we deploy a new version of code for the web application, we also deploy the web.config file.

Recently the operation team has raised a concern to this deployment process. They say, if someone change some settings in IIS and for that web.config has been updated for that, there is no way for the developers to know that change so that they can update the web.config in codebase (version control system). So eventually at the time of next deployment the web.config changes will be overridden by the old web.config.

There are two possible solutions can be taken:

1. Merge the web.config with server and codebase before deploy the code everytime.
2. Decouple the application configuration and IIS configuration in different configuration files.

My question is, what is the best practice to solve these kinds of problems in ASP.NET?

Comment: It is more important to learn what exact the changes your operation team would like to do. Most of the changes they want, can be added to `applicationHost.config` as location tags, so that different teams (developers/operation) manage different files (`web.config`/`applicationHost.config`). Is it what you meant by "Decouple the application configuration and IIS configuration in different configuration files"? I rather think such should be handled case by case. There is "best practice" at least from Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7+ introduced its distributed configuration which allowed for IIS as well as .NET configuration to live inside of Site/App/Directory web.config files.   One of the primary reasons for this is as follows:  In IIS 6, whenever an application team needed to deploy their application and make changes to settings like Default Document, they needed the IIS team involved because "Default Document" was an IIS configuration setting.  You could argue that Default Document settings for a particular application is not IIS configuration, but instead is Application configuration.  As result, the Application Team should own that configuration setting and deploy it as part of the application.

A bit more about IIS7+ configuration system:  Administrators are able to configure what settings are allowed to be set inside Web.config files.  For example, by default, "Default Document" is able to be set inside Web.config files, and Authentication settings like Windows Authentication are not.  The implementation can actually get complex, but if you'd like to read about it, you can see it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration.

Ultimately the best practice is for IIS Administrators to configuration the settings they want Application teams to manage (by delegating those settings to Web.config) and then not touch them.   In other words, if Default Document needs to be updated, then it is the Application Team's responsibility and they publish a new web.config file.   If the IIS team decides they want to manage Default Document, then they need to lock down the IIS configuration system to prohibit Default Document from being managed in the web.config files.